# Angular 5 LifeCycle Hook for Redisplay of Component

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular5

I am attempting to hook to the life-cycle event for the initial display/re-display of a component.

Per the [Angular documents](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) these component hooks seem to be my options:

- `ngOnInit()` - Called once after initial component initialization.
- `ngAfterContentInit()` - Called after every change detection run. This runs even on mouse over, hover, etc. events and IMHO is not ideal to hook into.
- `ngAfterContentChecked()` - Called after `ngAfterContentInit()` and `ngDoCheck()`.
- `ngAfterViewInit()` - Called once after every `ngAfterContentChecked()`
- `ngAfterViewChecked()` - Called after `ngAfterViewInit()` and after every `ngAfterContentChecked()`

So, basically what I am trying to find is the life-cycle hook that would be run once after display/redisplay of a tab using [Ng-Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

Which is the best lifecycle hook for this purpose?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is no life-cycle hook for re-display of a component unless you are destroying the component and then displaying it again (by a refresh for example). What are you trying to accomplish? There may be other ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: If the tab system uses ngIf, then the component is destroyed (and you can use ngOnInit()). If it's just conditionally showing, then you can't use a lifecycle hook and you'll have to just expose a method and call it when the tab changes.

Comment: There's no concept of 'redisplay' in Angular. If the component is being compiled, it doesn't matter for it if it was previously compiled. It's parent component's responsibility to let child component know that there is a difference. If third-party parent component wasn't built like, it's impossible. It may be solved by extending it or providing a new directive, depending on the case.